# Connect to WebSocket server on Asp.Net Core

Tags: websocket, asp.net-core

How to establish connection and send messages to remote WebSocket server from ASP.NET Core?
Is it possible now or I should wait for SignalR library to achieve this?

Comment: Did you had a look at https://github.com/aspnet/WebSockets/tree/1.0.0-rc2/src? It's an websockets middleware for ASP.NET Core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for System.Net.WebSockets.Client. It's available, but not on all platforms (https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2486).